# Android App crashes on startup only on SGS2

Tags: android, crash, app-startup

I am having an app in the store which runs fine on most devices but on one particular 
Samsung Galaxy S2 running Android 4.1.2 (version JZO54K.I9100XWLSS).

It crashes on startup without a crash-report from google or from crashlytics which i integrated. Its not actually a crash it just flashes the main activity a while until the phone shuts down:
A video of that behavior:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/523370/20131004_115027%5B1%5D.mpeg

Its a device from a user, so I cannot debug it locally. (Is there something to get a live logcat stream from the phone over the air?)

Has anyone experienced such a "crash" on start only affecting one particular device?
I have a SGS2 where it works without flaws. Could there be any hardware reasons resulting in such a crash e.g. Memory issue.

I know this problem is not likely to be resolved without any further source code / crashreports, but maybe someone can point me in the right direction.

best regards,
Mike

Comment: Can you check with the user and ask whether they have enabled the "Developer options"? If yes, which options (e.g., "Don't keep activities") are enabled?

Comment: I will check with the user, but I do not see which setting in the developer options could cause such a behaviour. But its worth a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually shoe rat saved my day!
Because shoe rat just commented on the case I am answering it for completeness.

The user enabled the option 
"Do not keep activities" which lead to this strange behavior, because an activity was killed during the splash screen.

As a future reminder to myself I will get rid of the splash screen because its not holo-style anyway.

Cost me a lot of time to figure this out and i probably wouldn't have found it without your help.